# Adjust map labels in some states of echarts?

Tags: vue.js, echarts

how can I adjust the map labels in some states?
because according to the image we have some values that are not very visible due to the small size of the state, I would like to arrive at a result like the image below that we have of a layout made in excel.

[this is the current result on the map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQJcP.png)

I would like to get this result

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKhko.png)

below my map option

```
    echarts.registerMap('BRASIL', jsonBR);
      option = {
        tooltip: {
          show: true,
          trigger: 'item',
          showDelay: 0,
          transitionDuration: 0.2,
          formatter: function (params) {
            // console.log('params', params);
            var value = params.value + '';
            //let regiao = '';
            value = value.replace(/(\d{1,3})(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '$1,');
            let result = ` <div class="overflow-x-auto">
                 <table class="table table-striped text-sm h-10">
                              <tr>
                                <td style="padding-left: 10px !important;padding-right: 0 !important;padding-top: 0 !important;padding-bottom: 0 !important;">
                                 <div class="text-base text-slate-500" style="text-align: center">${params.name}</div>
                                  <p style="font-size:10px;margin-top:-5px;height:20px;text-align: center">Região ${params?.data?.value[1]}</p>
                                </td>
                                </table>
                               <table class="table table-striped text-sm h-10">
                                 <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                      <th style="padding-left: 0px !important;padding-right: 0 !important;padding-top: 0 !important;padding-bottom: 0 !important;color: #565656;">
                                        <strong>Situação</strong></th>
                                      <th style="padding-left: 10px !important;padding-right: 0 !important;padding-top: 0 !important;padding-bottom: 0 !important;color: #565656;">
                                        <strong>Quantidade</strong></th>
                                      <th style="padding-left: 10px !important;padding-right: 0 !important;padding-top: 0 !important;padding-bottom: 0 !important;color: #565656;">
                                        <strong>%</strong></th>
                                    </tr>
                                 </thead>
                                 <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                       <td style="padding-left: 0px !important;padding-right: 0 !important;padding-top: 0 !important;padding-bottom: 0 !important;">Trânsito no Prazo</td>
                                       <td style="padding-left: 10px !important;padding-right: 0 !important;padding-top: 0 !important;padding-bottom: 0 !important;">${params?.data?.value[2].qt_transitonoprazo}</td>
                                       <td style="padding-left: 10px !important;padding-right: 0 !important;padding-top: 0 !important;padding-bottom: 0 !important;">${params?.data?.value[2].pr_transitonoprazo} %</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                       <td style="padding-left: 0px !important;padding-right: 0 !important;padding-top: 0 !important;padding-bottom: 0 !important;">Trânsito Fora do Prazo</td>
                                       <td style="padding-left: 10px !important;padding-right: 0 !important;padding-top: 0 !important;padding-bottom: 0 !important;">${params?.data?.value[2].qt_transitoforaprazo}</td>
                                       <td style="padding-left: 10px !important;padding-right: 0 !important;padding-top: 0 !important;padding-bottom: 0 !important;">${params?.data?.value[2].pr_transitoforaprazo} %</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                       <td style="padding-left: 0px !important;padding-right: 0 !important;padding-top: 0 !important;padding-bottom: 0 !important;">Entregue no Prazo</td>
                                       <td style="padding-left: 10px !important;padding-right: 0 !important;padding-top: 0 !important;padding-bottom: 0 !important;">${params?.data?.value[2].qt_entreguenoprazo}</td>
                                       <td style="padding-left: 10px !important;padding-right: 0 !important;padding-top: 0 !important;padding-bottom: 0 !important;">${params?.data?.value[2].pr_entreguenoprazo} %</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                       <td style="padding-left: 0px !important;padding-right: 0 !important;padding-top: 0 !important;padding-bottom: 0 !important;">Entregue Fora do Prazo</td>
                                       <td style="padding-left: 10px !important;padding-right: 0 !important;padding-top: 0 !important;padding-bottom: 0 !important;">${params?.data?.value[2].qt_entregueforaprazo}</td>
                                       <td style="padding-left: 10px !important;padding-right: 0 !important;padding-top: 0 !important;padding-bottom: 0 !important;">${params?.data?.value[2].pr_entregueforaprazo} %</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                       <td style="padding-left: 0px !important;padding-right: 0 !important;padding-top: 0 !important;padding-bottom: 0 !important;">Pendente de Embarque</td>
                                       <td style="padding-left: 10px !important;padding-right: 0 !important;padding-top: 0 !important;padding-bottom: 0 !important;">${params?.data?.value[2].qt_pendente}</td>
                                       <td style="padding-left: 10px !important;padding-right: 0 !important;padding-top: 0 !important;padding-bottom: 0 !important;">${params?.data?.value[2].pr_pendente} %</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                       <td style="padding-left: 0px !important;padding-right: 0 !important;padding-top: 0 !important;padding-bottom: 0 !important;">Recusado</td>
                                       <td style="padding-left: 10px !important;padding-right: 0 !important;padding-top: 0 !important;padding-bottom: 0 !important;">${params?.data?.value[2].qt_recusado}</td>
                                       <td style="padding-left: 10px !important;padding-right: 0 !important;padding-top: 0 !important;padding-bottom: 0 !important;">${params?.data?.value[2].pr_recusado} %</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                       <td style="padding-left: 0px !important;padding-right: 0 !important;padding-top: 0 !important;padding-bottom: 0 !important;">
                                        <strong>Total</strong></td>
                                       <td style="padding-left: 10px !important;padding-right: 0 !important;padding-top: 0 !important;padding-bottom: 0 !important;">
                                         <strong>${params?.data?.value[2].qt_total}</strong></td>
                                       <td style="padding-left: 10px !important;padding-right: 0 !important;padding-top: 0 !important;padding-bottom: 0 !important;">
                                        <strong></strong></td>
                                    </tr>
                                 </tbody>
                              </table>
                            </div> `;
            return result;
          },
          textStyle: {
            color: '#000',
            fontSize: 16,
          },
        },
        color: ['#FF6D60', '#F7D060', '#F3E99F', '#98D8AA', '#31C6D4', '#ADA2FF'],
        visualMap: {
          show: true,
          type: 'piecewise',
          showLabel: false,
          dimension: 1,
          top: 0,
          backgroundColor: '#fff',
          left: 'center',
          orient: 'horizontal',
          categories: ['CentroOeste', 'Nordeste', 'Norte', 'Sudeste', 'Sul', 'Exterior'],
          hoverLink: false,
          inRange: {
            color: {
              CentroOeste: '#FF6D60',
              Nordeste: '#F7D060',
              Norte: '#F3E99F',
              Sudeste: '#98D8AA',
              Sul: '#31C6D4',
              Exterior: '#ADA2FF',
            },
          },
          /* text: ['High', 'Low'],
            calculable: true,*/
        },
        toolbox: {
          show: false,
          //orient: 'vertical',
          left: 'left',
          top: 'top',
          feature: {
            dataView: { readOnly: false },
            restore: {},
            saveAsImage: {},
          },
        },
        series: [
          {
            name: '',
            type: 'map',
            //zoom: 2,
            scaleLimit: { min: 1.2, max: 12.0 },
            roam: true,
            map: 'BRASIL',
            avoidLabelOverlap: true,
            textAlign: 'center',
            label: {
              //mostra o nome do estado
              show: true,
              formatter: function (params) {
                return `${params.data.value[2].ds_uf}
  ${converters.valor(params.data.value[2].vl_fretetransportadora)}
  ${params.data.value[2].pr_frete} %`;
              },
            },
            emphasis: {
              disabled: false,
              label: {
                //mostra o nome quando passa o mouse
                show: true,
              },
              itemStyle: {
                // color: "red",
                areaColor: '#eee',
                // opacity: 1,
                // borderWidth: 2
                shadowColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)',
                shadowBlur: 5,
              },
            },
            select: {
              disabled: true,
            },
            itemStyle: {
              areaColor: '#eee',
              color: 'red',
              borderWidth: 1,
              // shadowColor: "blue"
              label: {
                show: true,
                textStyle: {
                  color: 'white',
                  fontSize: 13,
                },
              },
            },
            data: dataMapa.value,
          },
        ],
      };
```